# Are there standard questionnaires for comparing 2 different UIs?

Tags: website-design, user-experience

For my research I am going to create a new UI for a system and test if that makes people able to use the system better, able to learn it more easily and more satisfied. I test the first two with some tasks, but the last I think will require a questionnaire.
I've looked around and found some papers and questionnaires but they all focus on the user satisfaction (or something else they measure) of a single specific UI. Examples would be found in the paper "Standardized Usability Questionnaires: Features and Quality Focus", 2016, but include USE, SUS and PSSQ.

Does anyone here know of a questionnaire for UI comparison that focuses on or at least has comparative questions, eg. "I prefer version X over version Y" or "Compared to version X, version Y feels more responsive"?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I think this would be better asked on [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Sorry, I'm voting to close as it's off-topic here.

Comment: For in the future: Is there some kind of overall list of the stack exchanges? I got her via a question by someone else that I found on google, and going that way if there are so many seperate stack exchanges it is hard to find the right one

Comment: Yes there is a list. https://stackexchange.com/sites#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question but it's misled in terms of the sorts of questions that you're looking for. For a product, you should be focused on understanding things like "is this user aware of this feature", "what do they think this button will do", "can they find X", "were they able to do what they set out to do", etc. Understanding things like this are WAY more important than their perceived favoritism.

As such, it's more useful to show users a UI and have them try to do certain tasks and ask some questions focused on understanding, like "what do you think this does", before they do it. Then analyze that and learn from it. At the VERY end if you want to ask a subjective question like "what parts of this did you like and not like" it might can help but that shouldn't be the focus.

There's a lot of names for this sort of thing but "user testing" and "user interview" are probably good to start from to learn more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will discuss this with my supervisors and then we might use one of the existing questionnaires once for each system.

Comment: As I mentioned I am going to have users to tasks and see whether they can do them faster, and whether they can do it correct more of the time, and that is the focus, but as a side thing we also want to know whether users experience the new design as better or not, and why.
We have been pretty focused recently on 'how do we know whether we improved anything compared to the old design' which is why I was looking for a test that involves the favoritism

Comment: How designs compare should be based on feature usage, speed of accomplishing a task, and those sorts of metrics. Asking users what they like is not a good judge because most people like what they're used to for a while until they get used to the new system. If you asked carriage and buggy users what they wanted they would say a faster horse, not a car.